# Эхо-бот в телеграмме не отвечает на сообщения

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Написал эхо-бота для телеграмма, а он не реагирует на сообщения. При этом в командной строке не вылезает никаких ошибок. Выключил Privacy Mode в настройках.

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def ans(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте TOKEN для Вашего бота. Код рабочий
[image: общение с ботом]

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего **проблема** заключается в том, что **нет данной строчки** кода: `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Вот пример другого эхо-бота:

```
import config
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message): # Название функции не играет никакой роли
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Также проблема может заключатся в том, что токен указан неверный.